# ImageView in JavaFX not keeping proper size

Tags: java, javafx

I am using this format to place an image as a background picture.

```
final VBox mainroot = new VBox();
mainroot.getChildren().addAll(backbutton,heroship);

final StackPane mainstackPane = new StackPane();
mainstackPane.getChildren().addAll(iv2,mainroot); 

final HBox hbox = new HBox(mainstackPane);
```

iv2 is my image iteself, created like this

```
final Image imagegame = new Image(bcolor,width,height, false, false);
ImageView iv2 = new ImageView();
iv2.setImage(imagegame);
iv2.setPreserveRatio(true);
iv2.setFitWidth(width);
iv2.setFitHeight(height);
```

As well, I am adding a set amount of Labels using an array and a for loop,

```
Label[] alienship = new Label[10];
for (int i=0;i<alienship.length;i++)
{
    mainroot.getChildren().add(alienship[i]);
}
```

My problem is, every time I change the array of Labels size lets say from 10 to 20, the image itself shifts downwards and I would have to translate it back up to fit.

I have tried using both a VBox and an HBox but I am not able to see a difference in my result.

I have also tried to use .setFitWidth() and .setFitHeight() but nothing helped.

With    Label[] alienship = new Label[10];
Result: http://puu.sh/eAihN/c5c7f38ef0.jpg
(In this case I would have used .setTranslate to allign it back up.

---

With Label[] alienship = new Label[20];
Result: http://puu.sh/eAiqz/3b4280b63b.jpg

What can I do to fix this issue and ensure it stays alligned no matter what size I set the array to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

The problem is not with the ImageView, but with the Layout/Container that you chose to add `heroship` and `alienship`.

[`VBox`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html) is a layout whose height depends on the no of children and height of each child. When the number of `alienship` increases the `VBox height` will increase to accommodate all the children.

**Solution**

You must consider a layout which can add any number of children, without any effect on the width and height of the container. Consider [StackPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html)

Quick fix is to make the VBox as the parent of the StackPane. Add the Image and the space ships to the StackPane, then add the Button and the StackPane to your VBox. Finally adding the VBox to your HBox.

```
final StackPane mainstackPane = new StackPane();
mainstackPane.getChildren().addAll(iv2, heroship); 

final VBox mainroot = new VBox();
mainroot.getChildren().addAll(backbutton, mainstackPane);

final HBox hbox = new HBox(mainroot);
```

Add all your alienships to the StackPane instead of adding them to the VBox

```
Label[] alienship = new Label[10];
for (int i=0;i<alienship.length;i++)
{
    mainstackPane.getChildren().add(alienship[i]);
}
```